# Integral of exponential function with polynomial argument

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am looking for an effcient way to evaluate

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\  e^{-ax+bx^2+cx^4}\\
\text{where } a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+
$$

I have already read about a solution involving the series expansion of the exponential here [Computing the integrals of the form $\exp(P(x))$, $P(x)$ a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149830/computing-the-integrals-of-the-form-exppx-px-a-polynomial) but I am looking for something computationally more efficient...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for a numerical method?

Comment: Well, an analytical solution in closed form would be cool, but I would also go for an efficient numerical solution. The evaluation of this integral is at the very core of the loop of my code so it better be fast ;)

Comment: any thoughts about the fact that the integral does in fact not converge?

Comment: I am somewhat flummoxed that the integral does not converge. Physically this does not make sense as it corresponds to the calculation of an expectation value. I am currently thinking about the constants a, b, and c... and about ways to rephrase my entire problem. I think I have some homework to do!

Thanks for your help so far. I might get back to you here as soon as I am somewhat clearer on my problem definition. Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is very simple. In fact the integral does not converge as $c>0$.

Comment: Is it possible to add a few more details regarding this response? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: For $c>0$ the integrand does not go to 0 for $|x|\to\infty$ and thus the integral diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Regards

Answer (score 1):

One way to begin to attack this is to understand what the parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$ represent.  Obviously, $c<0$ for convergence.  But what if $c$ is very small in the following sense:

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: \exp{[-M (x^2 + a x) + c x^4]} $$

as $M \rightarrow \infty$?  Then you can apply [Laplace's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) and expand the integral in an asymptotic expansion in $M$.  That is, a rescaling of the argument of the exponential can provide a simple approximation to the integral, in certain cases, where all you need at worst are Error functions and their derivatives.

In the most general case, you may try a simple numerical technique based on estimations of the extent of the exponential along the real axis.