# Numerical integration of $\sin(p_{m})$ and $\cos(p_{m})$ for a polynomial $p_{m}$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I was wondering if anyone knew about any numerical methods specifically designed for integrating functions of the form $\sin(p_{m})$ and $\cos(p_{m})$ where $p_{m}$ is a polynomial of degree $m$. I don't think $m$ will be too large in the application, but it will probably be at least $4$. I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272248/integral-of-exponential-function-with-polynomial-argument) thread about Laplace's method but I'm not really sure that's what I want.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is an adaptive variant of a basic quadrature rule like Simpson's rule.

Comment: I think you should give more information. In particular, why are the standard adaptive integration routines not working for you? Is the integration region large enough that the integral is very oscillatory? In that case, why can't you use standard oscillatory integral algorithms? There could be some deeper issues here, but you should say why the standard approaches aren't working for you.

Comment: @Kirill Actually, the integration range is small, but I need high accuracy. Standard methods may be fine, but I just wanted to check if there was anything specifically for this problem.

Comment: I see. I think this question is maybe a bit too vague, then.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [Gaussian quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) with weight functions $w(x)=\sin(p_m)$ and $w(x)=\cos(p_m)$. For any weight function there is a family of orthogonal polynomials related to that function in $[a,b]$. This family can be obtained by [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) process on $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n$.

Let $w(x)$ be a weight function in $[a,b]$ and $\{p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ be a family of orthogonal polynomials with degree of $p_k=k$. Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be the roots of $p_n(x)$ and
$$
L_i(x)=\prod_{j=1, j\ne i}^{n}{\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}}
$$
be the [Lagrange polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) of these roots. Then the Gaussian quadrature is defined by
$$
\int_a^b{w(x)f(x)dx}\approx \sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_i f(x_i)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\int_a^b{w(x)L_i(x)dx} \right) f(x_i)}
$$
The above formula is exact for all polynomials of degree $\le 2n-1$. This is better than [Newton-Cotes formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas) since the $(n+1)$ points Newton-Cotes rule is exact for polynomials of degree $\le n$ ($n$ odd) or $\le (n+1)$ ($n$ even).

Comment: The question makes it sound like $f(x)=1$.

Comment: You are right. I didn't think about it at all.